# Не находит регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

На сайте есть многострочная статья с разделом "содержание" вначале:

```
<div class="mce-toc">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#mcetoc_1cfumeivr2t">Переменные</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#mcetoc_1cfumeivr2u">Копирование переменных</a></li>
   <li><a href="#mcetoc_1cfumeivr2v">Типы переменных</a>
   <ul>
   ...
</div>
```

Нужно обернуть содержимое блока .mce-toc в другой контейнер. Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью preg_replace, но в ответ приходит NULL. Не пойму в чем причина.

```
    $pattern = '/<div class="mce-toc">((\s|.)*?)<\/div>/mu';
    $replacement = '<div class="spoiler">
                        <a class="spoiler-link" href="">
                            <span>Содержание</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="spoiler_main">
                            <div class="spoiler-content">
                                $1
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    var_dump($matches); //array(0) { }
    var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text)); //NULL
```

Comment: Контрольный пример работает https://ideone.com/ug6USq  Вы чего то не договариваете, например действительно ли приведенный текст находиться в переменной $text

Comment: В сервисе https://regex101.com/ тоже всё работает. Вот потому-то и странно что результат null. Я проверил все переменные.

Comment: как видите на ideone прямо в php работает. так что поврежденный входящий текст - единственно возможное объяснение. так что проверяйте как именно текст попадает в перменную

Comment: https://ideone.com/b8fa7m Не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю это какое то внутреннее ограничение по времени выполнения (или бактреку)  функций `preg_*`. На приведенном вами в комментариях примере реального текста regex101.com показывает 10k шагов выполнения данной регулярки. Немного доработав регулярку получил 1200 шагов. `/<div class="mce-toc">(([^<]++|.)*?)<\/div>/mus`. При этом php [отработал](https://ideone.com/C2TapT).

Но учитывая такое поведение preg_replace, можно ожидать что на более крупных текстах оно может опять сломаться. Исходя из этого могу порекомендовать вместо регулярок использовать строковые функции поиска и замены.